# get the value of required key from json tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

The below tree is dynamically updating, so the level is not same all the time. It can have n*n deepest level & 'n' no.of children.

```
var data = {
    “name”: “abc”,
    "children": [
        {
            “name”: “def”,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name”: “ghi”
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            “name”: “jkl”
        }
    ]
};
```

From the above Json tree how can I get the all 'name' key values. i.e, (expected result **abcdefghijkl**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use recursive function.

```js
var data = {
  name: 'abc',
  children: [{
      name: 'def',
      children: [{
        name: 'ghi'
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'jkl'
    }
  ]
};

var output = "";

function getName(obj) {
  output += obj.name;
  if (obj.children) {
    obj.children.forEach(children => {
      getName(children);
    });
  }
}
getName(data);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach and separate name and children.

```js
const
    getNames = ({ name, children = [] }) => [name, ...children.flatMap(getNames)],
    data = { name: "abc", children: [{ name: "def", children: [{ name: "ghi" }] }, { name: "jkl" }] },
    result = getNames(data);

console.log(result.join(''));
console.log(result);
```

Just a string string.

```js
const
    getNames = ({ name, children = [] }) => name + children.map(getNames).join(''),
    data = { name: "abc", children: [{ name: "def", children: [{ name: "ghi" }] }, { name: "jkl" }] },
    result = getNames(data);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A lil bit confusing with the question, but this is my way

```
const data = {
  name: "abc",
  children: [
    {
      name: "def",
      children: [
        {
          name: "ghi",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "jkl",
    },
  ],
};

const string = `${data.name}${data.children
  .map((e) => {
    return e.name;
  })
  .join("")}`;

console.log(string);
```